# Spacing between logo and menu

Tags: wordpress, margin, spacing

Does anyone know how to get rid of the spacing between the logo on the top left and the menu bar under it? I would like them to align on top of each other. This my website http://www.bigredfro.com

I made a child theme and tried changing some of the code in the css.style file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the problem.

```
.site-branding {
    min-height: 135px;
}
```

Override it with `0px`.

[image]